# If a std::map is cleared is it ensured, that the memory is deallocated

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector, stdmap

If a `std::vector vec` is cleared with `vec.clear()` the allocated memory must not be deallocated immediately. The `size` of the vector will be zero, but the `capacity` will/can be unchanged.

This is a very beneficial behaviour, since one can clear a large vector and assign new values to it, without the need of an expensive memory de/allocation. Also the memory will be less de-fragmented.

One can enforce that with `vec.shrink_to_fit()` [shrink_to_fit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit).

`std::map` has a `clear` function, but no `shrink_to_fit`. What happens to the needed memory to store the map after a `clear`?

cppreference.com states that [map.clear()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/clear) erases all elements from the container. After this call, size() returns zero.

Comment: The tree is destroyed, so the nodes are deallocated. I suppose the tree could keep them, but I don't think anyone does this.

Comment: What happens to the memory for the nodes is up to the allocator used with the map. Same as with any node based container. Vector is different on account of needing to ensure contiguity.

Comment: map does not store its elements in contiguous memory, so there is little benefit of having capacity that is not actually used

Comment: Memory allocation is a multi-stage buffering system. When memory is cleared the *container* may not release the memory to the *allocator*. Allocator which may implement also some buffering, and may not release the memory to the *user-space memory* (libc) management library, which also implement buffering and may not release the *virtual-memory mapping* managed by the *kernel*, which may keep the *physical memory* booked for a while before releasing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One can enforce that with vec.shrink_to_fit() shrink_to_fit.

Actually, `shrink_to_fit` doesn't *enforce* deallocation of memory. It simply allows it. The implementation is allowed to not deallocate.

> If a std::map is cleared is it ensured, that the memory is deallocated

No. The only case where standard containers are guaranteed to deallocate their memory is when they are destroyed.

Map doesn't have a concept of capacity that vector has, so it doesn't need shrink_to_fit. A map after clear is in same situation as a vector is after clear + shrink_to_fit: It doesn't need to have any memory allocated... but it is not prohibited to have it allocated either.