# What does std::unordered_map::clear() do?

Tags: c++, std, unordered-map

I have a simple piece of code:

```
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")
#include <unordered_map>
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
        
    static constexpr const int MaxN = 2e6 + 69;
    map.reserve(MaxN);
    
    int t = 1000;
    while (t--)
    {
        map.clear();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

What this code does is just create a huge `std::unordered_map`, reserve it a large amount of memory on the heap while still keeping it empty, and clear it 1000 times. To my surprise, it takes more than a second to execute this program.

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/clear), `std::unordered_map::clear` is linear in the **number of elements**, which is 0, not the number of buckets. Therefore, this function should do nothing in my program, and should take much less than a millisecond.

Trying to further analyze the code, I've written this:

```
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <map>
template <typename T>
struct verbose_pointer
{
    using element_type = T;
    T* value = nullptr;
    static std::map<T*, std::size_t> accessTimes;   
//  T & operator[](std::size_t n)
//  {
//      ++(*count);
//      return value[n];
//  }
    T * operator ->() const
    {
        ++accessTimes[value];
        return value;
    }
//  T & operator *() const
//  {
//      ++(*count);
//      return *value;
//  }
    static void operator delete(void * ptr)
    {
        T * toErase = (static_cast<verbose_pointer *>(ptr))->value;
        std::cerr << "Deleted " << toErase << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Address " << toErase << " accessed " << accessTimes[toErase] << " times." << std::endl;
        accessTimes.erase(toErase);
        ::operator delete(toErase);
    }
    verbose_pointer(void* ptr) : value(static_cast <T*>(ptr)) 
    {
        std::cerr << "I'm constructed from pointer: " << ptr << std::endl;
    }
    
    static verbose_pointer pointer_to(T & t) { return verbose_pointer(&t); }
    ~verbose_pointer()
    {
    }
};
template <typename T>
std::map<T*, std::size_t> verbose_pointer<T>::accessTimes;
template <typename T>
class verbose_allocator
{
    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = verbose_pointer<T>;
        constexpr verbose_allocator() noexcept = default;
        constexpr verbose_allocator(const verbose_allocator & other) noexcept = default;
        template <typename U>
        constexpr verbose_allocator(const verbose_allocator<U> & other) noexcept {}
        pointer allocate(std::size_t n)
        {
            std::cout << (n * sizeof(T)) << " bytes allocated." << std::endl;
            return static_cast<pointer>(::operator new(n * sizeof(T)));
        }
        void deallocate(pointer p, std::size_t n)
        {
            std::cout << (n * sizeof(T)) << " bytes deallocated." << std::endl;
            pointer::operator delete(&p);
        }
};
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, verbose_allocator<std::pair<const int, int>>>
        verbose_map;
        
    static constexpr const int MaxN = 2e6 + 69;
    verbose_map.reserve(MaxN);
    
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
        
    int t = 1000;
    while (t--)
    {
        verbose_map.clear();
    }
    
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << "1000 clear() runs take " << duration.count() << " milliseconds." << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of my code is:

```
8579908 bytes allocated.
I'm constructed from pointer: 0xd09020
1000 clear() runs take 1139 milliseconds.
I'm constructed from pointer: 0xd09020
8579908 bytes deallocated.
Deleted 0xd09020
Address 0xd09020 accessed 1 times.
```

It seems that a huge block of memory is allocated once in the `reserve()` statement, and deallocated once when the map goes out of scope, just like what I expected. And also, the pointer is only being accessed once.

So why does 1000 `std::unordered_map::clear()` operations take so much time? What does GCC's implementation do here?

Comment: Please show how you measure the time taken for the various operations -- I don't see anything in the code shown.  Also note that measuring the performance of unoptimized code is largely pointless.  Remove the `#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")` directive.

Comment: @G.M. I use console pauser in Dev-C++ so it always shows me the execution time after the code is executed.

Comment: How does the time change if you vary `MaxN` and `t` independently?

Comment: First, you should properly measure amount of time it takes to clear. Simply checking out how much time program takes is not the correct way as there is start up and termination involved which might take time. Furthermore, reserving `2000000` elements will surely take a while as it requires at least `2000000` calls to `new` which is a relatively slow operation - in fact it surely requires more calls to `new` by a factor of 2 or more.

Comment: I'd imagine `reserve` is probably taking most of the time.

Comment: @ChrisMM I've edited the code, and added a time measuring function to prove that clear() is taking most of the time.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Also see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67922

Comment: @AlanBirtles GDB doesn't seem to work on my computer.

Comment: You cannot profile anything reliably with optimizations disabled ...

Comment: Are you testing an optimized build or a unoptimized debug build? Unoptimized builds (the default for most compilers) only care about generating code that is easy to debug and performance is secondary and debug builds are notoriously slow and do lots of things that the optimizer usually just removes. Always test optimized builds if you want to know how your code will/can perform in the real world. Timing unoptimized debug builds is a waste of time. "#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")" seems to point at a weird, non-standard, way of ensuring a non-optimal unoptimized build.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I ensure that optimizations are disabled to ensure that the whole "while" loop with no effects are not optimized away. Adding a single ```verbose_map.insert({rand(), rand()})``` before the ```clear()``` statement while compiling with -O3 gives the same performance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The definition of `reserve(N)` for unordered associative containers is that it allocates enough buckets such that the load factor of the table would be less than or equal to the max load factor if there were `N` elements in the container. The default value of the max load factor is 1, therefore `reserve` must allocate at least 2,000,069 buckets.

It's true that `clear()` is specified to take linear time, and complexity requirements are in terms of the number of elements in the container. But to be more precise: complexity requirements specify the *number of operations on container elements*. For example, if a container contains 1 element, then there must be some constant upper bound on the number of operations the container can do on that element when `clear()` is called. But there is no limit to how much time the container can spend on "bookkeeping" in addition to such operations. Therefore, it's quite possible that `clear()` for a hash-based container may take additional time linear in the number of buckets, without violating the standard.

I looked at the [libstdc++ implementation of `clear()`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/hashtable.h#L2069). It does one pass of iterating through all the elements and destroying them, then a `memset` to reset all bucket pointers to null. So in fact it *always* takes extra time linear in the number of buckets, even if this is "unnecessary" due to there having been no elements in the first place. So your program's 1000 `clear()` iterations would perform at least 2,000,069,000 operations with such an implementation (assuming it takes one operation to zero one pointer-sized memory location).

Comment: Hi @BrianBi I was wondering whether does exactly the same hold for `map` (ordered map)? Thanks

Comment: @MangoPizza That should be posted as a new question, not a comment.

Comment: You probably shouldn't reserve such a large map if you don't intent to fill it with that many elements. If you grow the map naturally it will have O(n) buckets and clear in O(n) time. You could try `shrink_to_fit`, then only the first clear will take a lot of time.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289808/if-a-stdmap-is-cleared-is-it-ensured-that-the-memory-is-deallocated says that `map` already has `shrink_to_fit`. So it shouldn't be a problem??

Comment: use it, benchmark it, enjoy