# Will std::unordered_map::clear() be slower than std::map::clear() because clear operations are "carried on" in the former?

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, unordered-map

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710308/what-does-stdunordered-mapclear-do/) and from what I can get is that `unordered_map` practically works linear in number of elements + number of buckets.

So, let's say, I have code, which

1. adds arbitrary number of elements to `std::unordered_map`
2. then `clear()` the `std::unordered_map`
3. repeat this multiple times.

If I had lot of elements at any point of the total execution (in step 1), the `clear` time will carry-on in future also, making code slow.

But, is this same issue also with `std::map`?

Thanks

Comment: Both linear in size. See complexity for: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/clear and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/clear

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the premise. You believe that if at any point you have a large number of elements in the map, _all_ future invocations of `clear` will be slow? Even if you `clear`, only add a few elements, and then `clear` again? I'm not sure that premise is supported by the linked question.

Comment: @NathanPierson "You believe that if at any point you have a large number of elements in the map, all future invocations of `clear` will be slow". Yes, that's what I am thinking.. For putting lot of element in `unordered_map` must reserve memory creating new buckets. See in the given answer "So your program's 1000 `clear()` iterations would perform at least 2,000,069,000 operations with such an implementation". So `1000` times `clear()` is called, and *each* time it has to `memset` `int(2e6) + 69` bucket pointers to null.

Comment: @NathanPierson I accept similar thing to happen here. One time, map has lots of elements, and then-onwards when erasing, all the buckets pointers must be reset.

Comment: But in the original question, each additional `clear` was preceded by an additional `reserve`. That doesn't support the idea that the time-complexity of `clear` is a ratchet, where if it takes a long time once it will always take at least that long every time in the future.

Comment: `std::map` doesn't have any buckets, it is a tree structure. After `clear()` the tree is gone.

Comment: @NathanPierson Probably, I am severely misunderstanding the question, but isn't the code `int t = 1000; while(t--){map.clear();}` Where is the additional `reserve`??

Comment: Ah, I see. Carry on, then.

Comment: @BoP Thank you very much. I hope that means that future `clear` operations in a `map` are not affected by their past. So, this is issue does not exist in `map`, and hence `clear()` time in `map` must be faster, right (following the question steps)? Thanks

Comment: "each time it has to memset int(2e6) + 69 bucket pointers to null" - the C++ Standard doesn't mandate this; an implementation could iterate over elements (which GCC stores in a forward-linked list); as it erases elements it can use their hash value (GCC saves it in the list) to clear the associated list-iterator in the hash table bucket.  Problems: 1) the clearing of hash buckets will be done in a pretty random order, which isn't cache friendly, and 2) if using % to map hash values to buckets (per GCC, clang), rather than bit-mask + power-of-2 bucket-counts, it's slow when load factor is high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When will std::map::clear() going to be faster that std::unordered_map::clear()?

Both have linear asymptotic complexity. You can time your code using both to see if either is measurably faster.

Note that if the destructor of the element is non-trivial, then `clear` of all containers has linear complexity. If the destructor is trivial, then the only standard containers that have less than linear complexity of `clear` are `std::vector` and `std::basic_string`.

---

Regarding the case of:

- grow container large
- clear
- insert few
- clear

The cost of latter clear being high that applies to `std::unordered_map` is not a problem that reproduces with `std::map`.

Comment: Hello, it seems I didn't explain the question properly. I have edited it to better reflect my question. Thanks

Comment: "The cost of latter clear being high that applies to `std::unordered_map` is *not* a problem that reproduces with `std::map`." This is exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: In fact, when I time the code. `map` works in `78ms` and `unordered_map` works in `1500ms`. There's a lot of difference!